# How to end a foreground service only when app has been closed

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

In my application I have a foreground service running. I am able to stop the foreground service without issues when the user logs out. However, if the user swipes to close the app or the app crashes, I'm not able to handle stopping the foreground.

OnSleep() is called when the application closes/crashes, however it's also called when the app is backgrounded. The foreground service I am using MUST continue to run if the app has been backgrounded but I need to stop the foreground service when it has been closed as opposed to backgrounded, for this reason I cannot stop the foreground service in the OnSleep() method.

Is there any way I can know when the application is closing (Not being backgrounded) so I can handle stopping the foreground service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution, that at least seems to work for my situation. It's also a simple fix. In the same class that I override OnStartCommand, I've also done an override of OnTaskRemoved which is fired when a task from the service has been removed by the user. So when a user swipes to close the app, OnTaskRemoved will be called, where you can handle closing the service.

```
public override void OnTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.N)
            {
                StopForeground(StopForegroundFlags.Remove);
            }
            else
            {
                StopForeground(true);
            }

            StopSelf();

            base.OnDestroy();
            System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
        }
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue by yourself, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it is beneficial to others to find this answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced with the same problem and the one of ways to implement it was to add a kind of "button" (action) to the notification of the foreground service using by [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts). So after closing the app user'll be able to close the foreground service just by tapping on the button included to the foreground notification.
From my prospective you also should override OnDestroy() method to do some stuff there and call StopForeground(an example). Because there can be some cases when the system decides to destroy service by itself (an example, Service is no longer used and is being removed.).

Comment: I have figured out a solution. Please see my answer, it may come in handy for you.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it makes sense to also override this method

Answer (score -1):

To Stop Foreground service, you can do this:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ForegroundService));
StopService(intent);
```

You can override OnDestroy to stop Foreground service.

```
StopService(new Intent(this, typeof(ForegroundService));
```

Or

```
StopSelf();
```

More detailed info about Foreground service , you can take a look [Foreground Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services)

and [Start Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/started-services)

Comment: I'm not asking how to stop a foreground service. I'm asking how I can know when my application is closing so I can prevent the foreground service running after the application has been closed. I think you have misunderstood my question.

Comment: Nice answer Cherry, I'm just wondering where (which class/part of my app) I can override OnDestroy to then call StopService() from?